# How to prevent logging for FirefoxDriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have WebDriver 2.41 and Firefox 28 and when my test creates instance of FirefoxDriver I see the following strings in console:

```
*** LOG addons.manager: Application has been upgraded
*** LOG addons.xpi: startup
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
*** LOG addons.xpi: Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
*** LOG addons.xpi: checkForChanges 
.................
```

How I can turn off this logging?

Comment: Can you please provide more information? E.g.: are you using any 3rd party testing framework. If you are using any testing framework, in their documents, you should be able to find how to turn off logging.

Answer (score 1):

Your Firefox version is upgraded which is not supported by Selenium. So downgrade to version 28. It will work fine.

You can download the required version of firefox from here:

> To stop updating the firefox automatically, uninstall the Mozilla
>   Maintenance  Service ( in Windows) & in **Tools** -> **Options** ->
>   **Advanced** -> 
>   **Updates Tab**, disable '**updates checking for addons & firefox**'

Best,

Anton